# What is the C++ equivalent of .net's currentProcess.MainModule?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, process

when doing this in c#

```
// get the current process
Process currentProcess  = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

I can do

```
currentProcess.MainModule
```

Is there any similar function  in c++?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you need? Do you want to get the location of the running code, or the location of the main .exe that started the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) at the decompiled source of `GetProcess()` it says:

```
public static Process GetCurrentProcess()
{
    return new Process(".", false, NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcessId(), null);
}
```

With `NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcessId()` being declared as

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();
```

Which referes to the [`GetCurrentProcessId` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The `MainModule` is defined as

```
public ProcessModule MainModule
{
    get
    {
        if (this.OperatingSystem.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            this.EnsureState((Process.State)3);
            ModuleInfo firstModuleInfo = 
                NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(this.processId);
            return new ProcessModule(firstModuleInfo);
        }
        ProcessModuleCollection processModuleCollection = this.Modules;
        this.EnsureState(Process.State.HaveProcessInfo);
        foreach (ProcessModule processModule in processModuleCollection)
        {
            if (processModule.moduleInfo.Id == this.processInfo.mainModuleId)
            {
                return processModule;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

which in turn seems to get down to the [`EnumProcessModules` native function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So by both using the `GetCurrentProcessId` and the `EnumProcessModules` function you should be able to get a similar result to

```
currentProcess.MainModule
```

Comment: I don't get this. You're going to call EnumProcessModules to enumerate the module handles and then wait until you see the module handle which equals `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` and then return that one?! For real?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry that my answer was too complicated. Back in the MFC ways I did it the same as you described (with some `Afx` prefix, IIRC). I just outlined an (incomplete, as you said) path through the .NET Framework as it _seems_ it is doing it.

Comment: .net libs are maintaining wrapper classes around module handles. Not your fault that your answer was accepted even though a one line version exists! I just want the asker to understand that trivial solutions exist.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are referring to Windows. If so then you need this:

```
GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

This returns the module handle of the module used to create the process. Find full details in the documentation for [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx).

If you want the file name of the module, rather than the module handle, then you need [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) instead.